# Spring WebFlow future and version

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

This is more to Spring Team supporting Spring WebFlow --

What is the Spring WebFlow road-map.  Can you describe its version convention how come it differs from rest of the core Spring Offerings.

Ex Spring 4 support offered in Spring WebFlow 2.4 not 3. 
Why did it stay at version 2.X and not moved to 3?

Also I heard a rumor that Spring WebFlow will not be supported is this true?

Thanks.

Comment: apparently the project is pretty much dead. RIP Spring WebFlow